# variables outside loop

Tags: php, variables, loops, foreach

I want to use all `$gamename` varibles again:

```
foreach($gamelist as $e){
            $chunks = explode('/',$e->nodeValue);
            $gamename = substr($chunks[2],0,-5);
            echo $gamename;
            echo "<br/>";
        }
 getObjects($fullPath,$folder,$gamename)
```

As I saw `$gamename` is undefined outside the foreach loop.

Comment: I want to use all $gamename variables again

Comment: Please check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) how to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your edit, you would need something like:

```
$gamenames = array();

foreach($gamelist as $e){
            $chunks = explode('/',$e->nodeValue);
            $gamename = substr($chunks[2],0,-5);
            echo $gamename;
            $gamenames[] = $gamename;
            echo "<br/>";
        }

// $gamenames is an array containing all game names
getObjects($fullPath,$folder,$gamenames[0])    // for the first game name
```

Comment: Someone who understood what I was talking about. Thanks.

Comment: @George Thanks, but it was actually your comment below the question that did it. You might want to add that to the question to get rid of the down-votes.

Answer (score 3):

out the loop `$gamename` had the value of the last iterate,

or `undefined` if the loop never run (`$gamelist` is empty)

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: gamename

Answer (score 2):

for loops have local scope, meaning that variables declaring inside them don't exist outside the execution of the loop, if you want to reuse the $gamename variables you should create them outside the loop, refer to @jeroen's post for an example.